# how to find difference between two dates?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates(one is current date for app launch another one is current date for app killed or going to background )

app launch,

```
 var start_time  
 var end_time  

       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
       start_time = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

app go to background,

```
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

       end_time = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: Why do you save `String` instead of `Date` objects?

Comment: i m new to ios . How to declare date object in globally..

Comment: You can simply create a date variable like you would any other type of variable: `var startDate: Date`